# When referencing a constant that fails Object.const_defined?, it doesn't invoke const_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am hitting a problem that a constant is being mapped to a wrong file. When debugging it, it shows weird things:

```
=> 1: class App::CloudCredential < App::Credential
   2: end
(byebug) Object.const_defined? "App::Credential"
false
(byebug) App::Credential
App::Shared::Credential
(byebug) App::Credential.class
Module
(byebug) App::Credential.name
"App::Shared::Credential"
```

My questions are that when `Object.const_defined? "App::Credential"` returns `false`,

1. why this wouldn't lead to `const_missing`?
2. why referencing it still print something (which is wrong) as if the constant is defined (against what `Object.const_defined?` tells me)
3. Basically I'd like to know under what situation (or what kind of test I can use in `byebug`) that would lead to `const_missing`. I am trying to find out why this `App::Credential` is being mapped to a complete wrong file (that of `App::Shared::Credential`)

*More information: This `App::Shared::Credential` is actually a module that is being included from the `class App::Credential` and this `App::Shared::Credential` has been included by another class.*

Thanks

Comment: "App::Credential" is a string, not a constant.

Comment: @jvillian: The OP said that `App::Credential` is a `Module`. Since `Module#const_defined?` expects a `String` or a `Symbol` (or something implicitly convertible, i.e. something that `responds_to?` either `to_str` or `to_sym`) , and `App::Credential` is a `Module`, you will get a "`TypeError`: no implicit conversion of `Module` into `String`".

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is not inconsistent at all.

When you try to access `App::Credential`, you are looking it up in the current constant namespace, but when you are using `const_defined?`, you are *explicitly* asking `Object` whether the constant is defined *there*. But `App::Credential` could be defined in a subclass of `Object`, not in `Object` directly, and then this would return `false`.

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    Baz = 42
  end

  const_defined? 'Bar::Baz'
  #=> true

  Object.const_defined? 'Bar::Baz'
  #=> false
end
```

Since you are looking in two different places, it is perfectly sensible to get two different answers.